# Why is std::integral defined with a type_trait and not with std::numeric_limits?

Tags: c++, c++20, type-traits, c++-concepts, numeric-limits

Why is the concept `std::integral` defined as

```
template < class T > concept integral = std::is_integral_v<T>;
```

and not as

```
template < class T > concept integral = std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer;
```

?

This means that the concept `std::integral` is restricted to "fundamental integral". For example, this is true:

```
std::numeric_limits<boost::multiprecision::cpp_int>::is_integer;
```

but this is false:

```
std::integral<boost::multiprecision::cpp_int>;
```

Is there any option to activate `std::integral` for user-defined types? What is missing e.g. in `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` so that it does not fulfill the concept `integral`?

Comment: Use a different concept that does what you want.

Comment: Yes. This is exactly the problem. I always had to use my own concept and never could use std::integral. But I guess there must be a convincing example where std::integral is appropriate.

Comment: `std::integral` implies some things that `std::numeric_limits<...>::is_integer` doesn't, like [triviality](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TrivialType), etc. By hacking it to be true for user-defined types, you'd break those assumptions.

Comment: Give me an example where you need these additional properties.

Comment: Anything that needs or expects trivality, e.g. `memcpy`ing the numbers. Also implicitly [starting their lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Implicit-lifetime_types).

Comment: Have you ever used std::integral? How often?

Answer (score 1):

> This means that the concept "std::integral" is restricted to "fundamental integral".

Yes; that's what `std::integral` is *for*: telling you if a type is an [integral type as defined by the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.fundamental#11).

If you want "integer type as defined by `numeric_limits`" or something else, you're going to need a different definition and therefore a different concept.

Comment: Do you have an example where std::integral is appropriate?

Comment: @HelmutZeisel: I don't understand. It's appropriate when you want/need to take an integral type. Maybe you're using that type as the type of a non-type template parameter. Maybe you're using it as the type for an `enum`'s underlying type. What matters is what question you want to ask.

Comment: Have you ever used std::integral? How often?

Comment: @HelmutZeisel: What does it matter?

Comment: If nobody is using std::integral, then something must be wrong with std::integral.

Comment: @HelmutZeisel: Nonsense. Not unless you're claiming that people would be using *your* definition for `integral` were it available. Is it not more likely that it's just not very common for people to write templates that *have* to take integers for some purpose? Just because you personally don't have a use for it doesn't mean it shouldn't be a concept.

Comment: Yes, this is my question: who is actually using std::integral?

Comment: @HelmutZeisel: Such a question is not permitted here. What you're asking is more like a survey, not a request for useful information. And we tend to prefer questions that are about useful information.